# Send e-mail with SMTP (Office 365)

Tags: web-part, email, sharepoint-online, office-365, smtp

I need to show a popup-window with a basic e-mail layout and send the e-mail after pressing the send button. The popup, I've created and also the webpart within. But when I want to send the e-mail, it crashes at the following line:

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(SMTP_HOST, SMTP_PORT);
```

With SMTP_HOST and SMTP_PORT the settings from my exchange online account:

```
private const string SMTP_HOST = "pod51014.outlook.com";
private const int SMTP_PORT = 587;
```

Error:

> System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission
>   of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed. at
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet) at
>   System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand() at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Initialize() at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient..ctor(String host, Int32 port) at ...

Does anyone know what's my problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the System.Net.Mail namespace or SPUtility.SendEmail with Office 365/Sandbox solutions.

[SPSE - Send email via code in Office365](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20552/send-email-via-code-in-office365)

Comment: Is there any other way to send an e-mail (WITH attachment)?

Comment: For example a webservice?

Comment: You can't call an external service (such as a web service) from a sandbox solution either. Perhaps you could use some way of kicking off a workflow or use a full trust proxy.

Comment: Did you come up with a workaround to this?