# Send e-mail with attachment (Office 365)

Tags: web-services, email, attachments, office-365, azure

Is it possible to send an e-mail with attachment in Office 365?
As attachment we would want the attachment from a listitem or a document from a document library.

Maybe with the use of webservices or other solutions... ?

FYI, I tried using a SMTP server in a custom webpart (which failed because SMTP isn't allowed)

Microsoft suggested this solution (but wasn't sure if it would work):

Connect with webservice to an Azure Service.

Is this solution possible? (I have no knowledge of Azure AT ALL)

Comment: For all intent purposes a duplicate of http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26380/send-e-mail-with-smtp-office-365

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, we created a Worker role in Windows Azure. With the client object model (ecmascript) we add items to a custom list on the rootweb of the sitecollection. We store everything we need about the e-mail message (from, to, cc, bcc, subject, body, attachmenturl's,...) After an item is created in this list, the workerrole on Azure starts working, processes the item and sends an e-mail to users, impersonating as the user in the "from" address.